# How to delete tracking code from links in PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink, affiliate

Hi I have a form in WordPress where users can submit a link to a product, but very often the links come with unnecessary baggage, like tracking codes. I would like to create a filter in WordPress and clean the links so they consist of just a working link. I would like to if possible confirm that the link still works or a method that will guarantee that the link will still work.

The main things I want to get rid of in links are `utm_source` and it's contents, `utm_medium` and it's contents, etc. Everything but the clean working link.

So for example, a link like this:
`https://www.serenaandlily.com/variationproduct?dwvar_m10055_size=Twin&dwvar_m10055_color=Chambray&pid=m10055&pdp=true&source=detail&utm_source=affiliate&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=pjdatafeed&publisherId=20648&clickId=2669312134#fo_c=745&fo_k=c0ebaf8359ca7853df8343e535533280&fo_s=pepperjam`

Will end up like this:

`https://www.serenaandlily.com/variationproduct?dwvar_m10055_size=Twin&dwvar_m10055_color=Chambray&pid=m10055`

I'd really appreciate if someone can lead me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want with [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). This code uses an array of unwanted parameters to decide what to delete from the query string:

```
$unwanted_params = array('utm_source', 'utm_medium', 'utm_campaign', 'clickId', 'publisherId', 'source', 'pdp', 'details', 'fo_k', 'fo_s');
$url = 'https://www.serenaandlily.com/variationproduct?dwvar_m10055_size=Twin&dwvar_m10055_color=Chambray&pid=m10055&pdp=true&source=detail&utm_source=affiliate&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=pjdatafeed&publisherId=20648&clickId=2669312134#fo_c=745&fo_k=c0ebaf8359ca7853df8343e535533280&fo_s=pepperjam';
list($path, $query_string) = explode('?', $url, 2);
// parse the query string
parse_str($query_string, $params);
// delete unwanted parameters
foreach ($unwanted_params as $p) unset($params[$p]);
// rebuild the query
$query_string = http_build_query($params);
// reassemble the URL
$url = $path . '?' . $query_string;
echo $url;
```

Output:

```
https://www.serenaandlily.com/variationproduct?dwvar_m10055_size=Twin&dwvar_m10055_color=Chambray&pid=m10055
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/vqHsL)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I noticed that in your answer I will have to pre-input all the unwanted parameters for it to work. My problem with this is that every URL has different parameters, so it won't be fool proof.

Comment: @alipik do you know which parameters you want to keep?

Comment: That really depends on each URL :) I would like the bare minimum working URL if possible.

Comment: @alipik but if you don't know what you want to get rid of, and you don't know what you want to keep, how can you process the URL? What defines the "bare minimum working URL"?

Comment: @alipik note that if those unwanted parameters don't exist in the URL you are processing, the code will still work, it will just ignore them.

Comment: I guess this is the best I'll get it. Performance wise, would there be anything bad about having ~30 unwanted parameters in the array?

Comment: @alipik obviously there is a performance impact but it is minimal - on my demo 1,000,000 iterations of the `foreach` loop take about 0.25 seconds.

Comment: Just curious, would it be hard to run this using Ajax on a form submit?

Comment: @alipik that sounds a bit complicated for a discussion in comments because form submits typically happen via post, not get. I suggest you ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the PHP itself. There is a function called `parse_url()` (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) which can give you all the URI params as array. After parsing, you can filter the parameters, remove the unwanted. Finally, use `http_build_query()` (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to build a string URI to return :)